# Error Handling method call on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch

I am getting the following non-terminating error in PowerShell.  I want to catch this and write-host a generic statement, rather than see the error.

Here is the output:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\PowerShell
>   Scripts\windowsUpdates.ps1:17 char:2
>   +     $a = $key.GetValue("LastSuccessTime")
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRec    ordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

My catch statement is currently not "catching" this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression - general](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335195/you-cannot-call-a-method-on-a-null-valued-expression-general)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525170/you-cannot-call-a-method-on-a-null-valued-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. I simply added `if($variable -eq $null){write-host "message";}`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options

Depending on where you are getting the null variable from you could add

> -ErrorAction Stop" 
>   after the command so that it treats the non-terminating error as a terminating error.

If that's not an option you could throw an error to force your catch statement to catch the error

> if($variable -eq $null){Throw("Variable is Null")}

Or you can make it so that all errors are treated as terminating errors so your catch statement will catch anything that is thrown

> $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

For more information look at the MSDN documentation here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx