# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell

I am simply trying to create a powershell script which calculates the md5 sum of an executable (a file).

My `.ps1` script:

```
$answer = Read-Host "File name and extension (ie; file.exe)"
$someFilePath = "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\$answer"

If (Test-Path $someFilePath){
    $stream = [System.IO.File]::Open("$someFilePath",[System.IO.Filemode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($stream))
    $hash
    $stream.Close()
} Else {
    Write-Host "Sorry, file $answer doesn't seem to exist."
}
```

Upon running my script I receive the following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\md5sum.ps1:6 char:29
+                             $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.Compute ...
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

To my understanding, this error means the script is attempting to do something, but another part of the script does not have any information to permit the first part of the script to work properly. In this case, `$hash`.

`Get-ExecutionPolicy` outputs `Unrestricted`.

**What is causing this error?**
**What exactly is my null valued expression?**

---

References:

[How to get an MD5 checksum in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521061/how-to-get-an-md5-checksum-in-powershell)

Comment: What is `$md5`? That variable is not in the code you show? That is null from what i see

Comment: How I missed that, I don't know. Thank you Matt for the prompt reply. My code now runs perfectly fine after adding my object. `$md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression - general](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335195/you-cannot-call-a-method-on-a-null-valued-expression-general)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The simple answer for this one is that you have an undeclared (null) variable. In this case it is `$md5`. From the comment you put this needed to be declared elsewhere in your code

```
$md5 = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
```

The error was because you are trying to execute a method that does not exist.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> $md5 | gm


   TypeName: System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider

Name                       MemberType Definition                                                                                                                            
----                       ---------- ----------                                                                                                                            
Clear                      Method     void Clear()                                                                                                                          
ComputeHash                Method     byte[] ComputeHash(System.IO.Stream inputStream), byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] buffer), byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] buffer, int offset, ...
```

The `.ComputeHash()` of  `$md5.ComputeHash()` was the null valued expression. Typing in gibberish would create the same effect.

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> $bagel.MakeMeABagel()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $bagel.MakeMeABagel()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

---

PowerShell by default allows this to happen as defined its [StrictMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-5.1)

> When **Set-StrictMode** is off, uninitialized variables (Version 1) are assumed to have a value of 0 (zero) or $Null, depending on type. References to non-existent properties return $Null, and the results of function syntax that is not valid vary with the error. Unnamed variables are not permitted.