# Azure DevOps - PowerApps package Deployer - You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: c#, azure-devops, dynamics-crm, devops

I am trying to run packagedeployer using PowerApps Deploy Package and getting an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression". 
This is a CRM Package solution that is created using Dynamics 365 SDK templates. Please find below the link with details

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/package-deployer/create-packages-package-deployer#create-a-package

[Azure DevOps Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SoAK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

The information is not enough to solve the problem, but i can suggest a way you can troubleshoot.

First, set the `system.debug` value to "true" in your pipeline `Variables`,

[image]

and then run the build again and you shall see the detailed exception message in the debug information(with ##[debug] before them) in the log information.

Most likely you will see it's a ps1 file that raised the error since the error message [you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_zh-CNSG849__850&sxsrf=ALeKk036NyM8XJAbLWPUu-O_OPGqyAg5mA%3A1582180859722&ei=-ylOXqjnK8rF4-EP_PqOkAk&q=you+cannot+call+a+method+on+a+null-valued+expression&oq=you+cannot+call+a+method+on+a+null-valued+expression&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i7i30l4j0i203j0i7i10i30j0i7i30l3.2847359.2847359..2847697...0.0..0.412.880.2-2j0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i302i39.Wbged9DBORQ&ved=0ahUKEwjo0PSAw9_nAhXK4jgGHXy9A5IQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) usually occurs in ps script and it should points out in which line which char you got the error.

Then, add a `PowerShell Script` task down below your `PowerApps Deploy Package`  task, add an `Inline` script using the [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) method:

```
Get-Content -Path {path you find in above task log information}
```

Now you are able to see which line in the script caused the problem and find a way to solve it, or update what you find in your question post and we will keep on.

Below are some reference links you can check:

[Troubleshoot the InvokeMethodOnNull Error with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/troubleshoot-the-invokemethodonnull-error-with-powershell/)

[You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525170/you-cannot-call-a-method-on-a-null-valued-expression/27525303)

Comment: Thank youYang, I raised the log level and could see that there were issues with the importconfig.xml. the issue was fixed after I updated the file.